# How to install Laravel 5.6 in xampp ubuntu?

Tags: php, composer-php, laravel-5.6

I'd been using php 5.6.* in Ubuntu for coding Laravel projects until Laravel was updated to 5.6 which required PHP 7.x.x. I then upgraded my xampp installation so that it carried php 7.

After installing the upgraded xampp, I don't seem to be able to create a laravel project again. When I run the command `composer create-project laravel/laravel blog`, I get the following errors:

> sh: 1: @php: not found
>   Script @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');" handling the post-root-package-install event returned with an error
>
> [RuntimeException]
>   Error Output: sh: 1: @php: not found

When I check my php version on the terminal using `php --version`, this is what I get:

> PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.4 (cli) 
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies

From my understanding, this is the php installation that comes with ubuntu. How do I make my laravel installation use the php from xampp which is more up to date?

I ran `composer update` in the project directory after the error message was thrown but that didn't help either.

If the problem is not with the Version of PHP (and I doubt this is true), how do I create a laravel 5.6 project with xampp in ubuntu?

Comment: How did you upgrade your PHP version? If you installed PHP 7, calling `php --version` should not display a version string telling you that 5.6.11 is installed

Comment: Next question: which version of composer do you use? The most recent one?